# Making Spark app work on m4 instances

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a pyspark application running on EMR (5.7.0) which processes about 140M json records.  Nothing terribly fancy outside of the size of the dataset -- main operations are map, filter, count, repartitionAndSort, and mapPartition.

This app runs on a cluster of 40 m3.2xlarge instances, but I wanted to try it on the m4 family (since I get access to beefier machines that way).

However, the executors fall over the the cluster is rendered inoperable (If I rerun my application, it fails far earlier with no available executors).

Here's the stack trace I get on failure.

```
17/08/26 15:51:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1118.0 in stage 145.0 (TID 72871, ip-172-22-247-134.ec2.internal, executor 91): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted
    at java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable.java:1043)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ReliableCheckpointRDD$.writePartitionToCheckpointFile(ReliableCheckpointRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ReliableCheckpointRDD$$anonfun$writeRDDToCheckpointDirectory$1.apply(ReliableCheckpointRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ReliableCheckpointRDD$$anonfun$writeRDDToCheckpointDirectory$1.apply(ReliableCheckpointRDD.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /checkpoints/48b56f21-7f74-429c-934c-0aea983c0175/rdd-359/.part-01118-attempt-0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 36 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
```

Any help?  Seems very weird that this can't run on m4-class machines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Spark on m4 instead of m3 on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39075540/running-spark-on-m4-instead-of-m3-on-aws)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate